# NGINX - url rewrite regular expression

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I have the url such as `example.com/page.php?username=test`. I want to rewrite this url into something like: `example.com/test` only if test follows the following regual expression: `/^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{1,35}+$/`, else 404 page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
# output: example.com/test
rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /page.php?username=$1;
```

**UPDATE:**

`{1,35}` This expression allow from 1 to 35 character

`{20}` That have to exactly 20 character

The `+` say minimum 1 character

The correct full rewrite rule:

```
# output: example.com/test
rewrite "^/([A-Za-z0-9_]{1,35})$" /page.php?username=$1;
```