# How should I redirect the url with parameters in nginx?

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

Here is my nginx.config

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.example.com;
      rewrite_log on;

      location ~^/v1/(\d+)\.html$ {
        return 301 http://dev-ra.example.com/v1?exid=$1;
      }
    }
}
```

Edited Note:
**I want this url should be redirected** http://www.example.com/v1/90943.html#featured **to** https://dev-ra.example.com/v1?exid=90943

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`rewrite ^/v1/([0-9]+).html /v1?exid=$1;`

P.S the question has been answered here [NGINX - url rewrite regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887401/nginx-url-rewrite-regular-expression)

P.S.s heres an example that will redirect to different domain using location block:

```
location ~ /v1/([0-9]+) {
    return 301 http://www.example2.org?exid=$1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, emke If it is different domain what I have to do, could you see my updated question above, please...

Comment: You can simply specify the domain, e.g `rewrite ^/v1/([0-9]+).html http://example1.com/v1?exid=$1;`

Comment: Hi ..Emke I have tried with what you have said and tried with some possible solutions please see my edited question above but still, I could not able to redirect. It remains the same page when I hit the  Url http://www.example.com/v1/90943.html#featured  it is not redirecting to  https://dev-ra.example.com/v1?exid=90943

Comment: @Ramyachinna that is weird. Could you try a few more alternatives. Remove ^ and $ from the rule and make sure you restart nginx.

Also when testing the rewrite after nginx restart, try editing the number in your url, as it may get cached and ignore the changes